# Math "collection" symbol

Tags: symbols

In my math book I see the notation for a collection of sets, which is like a fancy `C`. I don't know how to describe it beyond that. What's the LaTeX for it?

Comment: Should dustin's answer not help you, it would help if you could mention `which` math book we are talking about exactly.

Comment: In the future, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) could help you to find which symbol you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\mathcal{C}` maybe what you are looking for or `\mathfrak{C}`